# MongoDB auth issue

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have enabled auth on MongoDB and created an admin user using:

```
db.createUser(
  {  
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "***", 
    roles:
    [  
      { role: "root", db: "admin"  }, 
      { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
      { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
      { role: "readWrite", db: "deadline7db" },  
      { role: "dbOwner", db: "deadline7db" },  
      { role: "dbAdmin", db: "deadline7db" },  
      { role: "readWrite", db: "admin" },  
      { role: "dbOwner", db: "deadline7db_Jobs" },  
      { role: "dbOwner", db: "deadline7db_Tasks" },  
      { role: "dbAdmin", db: "deadline7db_Jobs" },  
    ]  
  }  
)
```

When I am trying to connect my application to this database using this user and password, it is connecting fine but throwing an error when trying to create index on `deadline7db_Jobs.Job` collection.

Below is the error:

> Command 'createIndexes' failed: not authorized on deadline7db_Jobs to execute command { createIndexes: "Jobs", indexes: [ { ns: "deadline7db_Jobs.Jobs", name: "Stat_1_Props.Pool_1_Props.Grp_1_IsSub_1", key: { Stat: 1, Props.Pool: 1, Props.Grp: 1, IsSub: 1 } } ] } (response: { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on deadline7db_Jobs to execute command { createIndexes: \"Jobs\", indexes: [ { ns: \"deadline7db_Jobs.Jobs\", name: \"Stat_1_Props.Pool_1_Props.Grp_1_IsSub_1\", key: { Stat: 1, Props.Pool: 1, Props.Grp: 1, IsSub: 1 } } ] }", "code" : 13 }).

Could anyone please have a look and let me know if I am missing any privilege or role.

Comment: What MongoDB version are you using? the ```createIndex``` method has been long deprecated in favor of ```collection.ensureIndex()```. Perhaps (just perhaps) the engine complains about an authorization problem because is a deprecated command.

Comment: Since you have granted `dbAdminAnyDatabase` and `readWriteAnyDatabase` on the `admin` database, all of the other per-db roles should be redundant. Are you definitely authenticating as this admin user against the `admin` database? Can you try to login with those credentials and ensure the same index from the `mongo` shell? Also, what version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @amenadiel: The exception here is referring to the [`createIndexes` server command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/#dbcmd.createIndexes), which is not the same as the deprecated [`db.collection.createIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) method. The `createIndexes` command was actually added in MongoDB 2.6 ;-).

Comment: Today I learnt there's a new command D:

Comment: I am using version 2.6.  That's right.. I am not using createIndex command , in my code its ensureIndex command only. I can create index when I try that in shell. It seems to be an issue with MongoDB C# driver. I am using its version 1.9.1. Anyone aware of such issue/bug in the C# driver?

Comment: Yes, you need to use ensureIndex( )...